# Laravel 8: or middleware for route

Tags: php, laravel, middleware, laravel-sanctum

I'm wanting the user to be able to log in with the 2 auths that I create. But when i add like below it throws an error and it makes me enter both auth styles i created while i want to just enter one of the two auth styles to login successfully.

I don't know if anyone has had the same situation as me. And can you tell me how to solve this problem?

Code route api.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum', 'auth.basic.once']], function () {
   Route::get('/images', [ImageController::class, 'index']);
});
```

I have tried some ways as follows but it still doesn't work and that includes Middleware Parameters: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#middleware-parameters

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum'|'auth.basic.once']], function () {
   Route::get('/images', [ImageController::class, 'index']);
});
```

OR

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum|auth.basic.once']], function () {
   Route::get('/images', [ImageController::class, 'index']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your auth as a guard, not as middleware. Docs about this are [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#adding-custom-guards).

After this you can set multiple guards:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:sanctum,basic'], function () {
   Route::get('/images', [ImageController::class, 'index']);
});
```